# Express and React, proxy in package.json works in dev, but why does it work with heroku in production?

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, proxy

I have **ReactJS** executed in `localhost:3000` and **Express** in `localhost:5000`. In order to route certain calls from React to Express I locate in the `package.json` of react (`/client` folder)

```
"proxy": {
  "/server*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:5000"
  }
}
```

And this works under development. This is, any `axios.get('/server_whatever')` gets redirected to **Express** that catches it with a `app.get('/server_*', (req, res) => {...`

And then, when deploying the **Heroku** I was expecting that this wouldn't work, since the proxy tag is ignored there.

But as far as I can see it seems to work (in **Heroku**). Here the question. **Why and how the calls are captured there?**

Comment: Is your local app still running?

Comment: It runs in the sense of it proxies the requests out-of-the-box. Why is that? is because Express is serving React as static files and thus everything is the same server?